# Rails-3.1 nested routes creating same action and controller, basic lack of knowledge

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, routes, nested, action

Doing the following routes configuration:

```
resources :cadeiras do
resources :professores 
end

resources :cadeiras do 
resources  :fichas
end

resources :fichas do
resources :exercicios
end
```

will generate me 2 different links to the same controller and action, running rake routes ill get something like:

```
 fichas GET    /fichas(.:format)  {:action=>"index", :controller=>"fichas"}
 cadeira_fichas GET    /cadeiras/:cadeira_id/fichas(.:format)    {:action=>"index", :controller=>"fichas"}
```

The first action will reference all the 'fichas' while the second on is referencing only 'fichas' from 'cadeiras' how is it possible to distinguish the two actions?

I would like to avoid three level nesting problems as described here :http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer is "you don't distinguish them" :

The exact same action is executed from the controller, rendering the exact same view. The difference is the collection of 'fichas' that get sent to the view:
  - in the first case, all fichas are available in the view
  - in the second case, only the 'fichas' related to the 'cadeira' are available in the view (e.g. `/cadeira/1/fichas` will display only the 'fichas' related to the 'cadeira' with `id` 1)

To determine which records to show (e.g.) in an index view, you can do something like this:

```
unless cadeira_id = params[:cadeira_id]
  @fichas = Ficha.all
else
  @fichas = Cadeira.find(cadeira_id).fichas
end
```

The rest is up to the view: it should render fichas the same way, you just chose which records are actually made available to it.

Comment: Thanks you for you quick response, but then if i'm rendering the path /cadeiras/1/fichas and /fichas/ they are both using the index action and index view and if I have the following code `class FichasController < ApplicationController
  # GET /fichas
  # GET /fichas.json
  def index
  @cadeira = Cadeira.find(params[:cadeira_id])
  @fichas = @cadeira.fichas
  @fichas = Ficha.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @fichas }
    end
  end`

Ill have two different content to show on different context links

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but I've updated my response to show how you can change which records are displayed depending on whether or not you're in a nested case.